# Is it possible to make pagination, having elements listed with forEach in a Toggleable Panel

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I would like to have 10 agencies per page, where every single one is in a Toogleable Panel.

The code of my page up to moment is:

```
    <c:forEach items="#{agencyBean.agencyList}" var="agency">

        <p:fieldset legend="${agency.tUser.name}" toggleable="true"
            toggleSpeed="500">
            <p:ajax event="toggle" listener="#{fieldsetBean.handleToggle}"
                update="growl" />

            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
                <p:graphicImage value="#{agencyBean.image}">
                    <f:param name="agencyId" value="#{agency.tUser.id}" />
                </p:graphicImage>
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" border="1">
                    Name: <h:outputText value="${agency.tUser.name}" /> 
                    Phone:<h:outputText value="${agency.tUser.phone}" /> 
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:fieldset>
    </c:forEach>
```

But all object from database are listed and it is not user friendly. Can you advice me how to split them on different pages? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try p:dataGrid?

```xhtml
<p:dataGrid var="agency" value="#{agencyBean.agencyList}" columns="1" rows="10" paginator="true">
    <p:fieldset legend="${agency.tUser.name}" toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="500">
        <p:ajax event="toggle" listener="#{fieldsetBean.handleToggle}" update="growl"/>

        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
            <p:graphicImage value="#{agencyBean.image}">
                <f:param name="agencyId" value="#{agency.tUser.id}"/>
            </p:graphicImage>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" border="1">
                Name: <h:outputText value="${agency.tUser.name}"/>
                Phone:<h:outputText value="${agency.tUser.phone}"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:fieldset>
</p:dataGrid>
```